# Polygon draw order issue

Tags: directx9, sharpdx, slimdx

I'm working on a software and I'd to move the rendering API from SlimDX to SharpDX. I've done that but I noticed that the solid polygon are not drawn correctly i.e., even if the polygon is at the back side of another polygon, part of it is visible, also part of the polygon lie inside terrain that is also visible. Below are the images from SlimDX implementation and SharpDX implementation for reference:

[image]

[image]

I tried to set the Stencil & ZBuffer but there are not working as expected. I've already applied DepthBias to it which worked fine with SlimDX but not with SharpDX.

Please let me know if, I'm missing something or I'm doing something wrong.

Update 1 (Polygon rendering):

```
// set the render state to device
device.SetRenderState(RenderState.AlphaTestEnable,
                      true);
device.SetRenderState(RenderState.AlphaBlendEnable,
                      true);
device.SetRenderState(RenderState.SourceBlend,
                      Blend.SourceAlpha);
device.SetRenderState(RenderState.SeparateAlphaBlendEnable,
                      true);
device.SetRenderState(RenderState.DestinationBlendAlpha,
                      Blend.One);
device.SetRenderState(RenderState.SourceBlendAlpha,
                      Blend.InverseDestinationAlpha);

// set the render state to the device
device.SetRenderState(RenderState.DepthBias,
                      -1E-06f);

this.effectVectoring.Begin(FX.None);

// binds the vertex buffer to device data stream
device.SetStreamSource(0,
                       this.vertexBuffer,
                       dataGeometry.FillVertexOffset,
                       stride);
// pass 1 to shader as a pass if it is 3D mode else 0
this.effectVectoring.BeginPass(is3D ? 1 : 0);
// renders the non-index geometric primitives using the data from current input stream
device.DrawPrimitives(SharpDX.Direct3D9.PrimitiveType.TriangleList,
                      0,
                      primitiveCount);
// end the pass
this.effectVectoring.EndPass();

this.effectVectoring.End();
device.SetRenderState(RenderState.AlphaBlendEnable,
                    false);
device.SetRenderState(RenderState.AlphaTestEnable,
                    false);
device.SetRenderState(RenderState.DepthBias,
                    0);
device.SetRenderState(RenderState.FillMode,
                    FillMode.Solid);
device.SetRenderState(RenderState.SeparateAlphaBlendEnable,
                    false);
```

Update 2 (Terrain rendering):

```
device.SetRenderState(RenderState.AlphaBlendEnable,
                      false);
device.SetRenderState(RenderState.AlphaTestEnable,
                      false);
device.SetRenderState(RenderState.CullMode,
                      Cull.Counterclockwise);

device.Indices = this.terrainIB;
device.SetStreamSource(0,
                       this.terrainVB,
                       0,
                       12);
device.VertexFormat = VertexFormat.Position;

// Set texture in effect...

effect.Begin(FX.None);

effect.BeginPass(pass);
device.DrawIndexedPrimitive(PrimitiveType.TriangleStrip,
                            baseVertexIndex,
                            0,
                            vertexCount,
                            startIndex,
                            primitiveCount);
effect.EndPass();

effect.End();
device.SetRenderState(RenderState.FillMode,
                      FillMode.Solid);
device.SetRenderState(RenderState.CullMode,
                      Cull.None);
```

Comment: Please show us a Minimal Complete Verifiable Example of the code needed to reproduce this problem, including where you set up your ZBuffer and depth writing/depth comparison tests. With that in hand, we can test potential solutions to ensure they will work for you.

Comment: @DMGregory I've updated the code snippet, please take a look. Thanks!

Comment: Is there a difference between how you're drawing the terrain, versus the structure on top of it?

Comment: @DMGregory it is different, above is the sample source of terrain rendering.

Comment: I don't see where your terrain's depth writing is set up. Is it possible it's defaulting to not write to the depth buffer, or that something is clearing depth between drawing the terrain and drawing what's on top? (Or conversely, if you draw the stuff on top first, could the terrain be always failing the z test?)

Comment: @DMGregory sorry for the late reply, actually I'm new to DirectX so, it took me some time to find out what to reply. As far as I understand we are not writing the depth buffer for terrain. First the top elements like vector entities are rendered, then the terrain is rendered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much debugging and understanding the code I found that the rendering code was correct but while creating the Viewport of the device I forgot to set the Min & Max Depth of it. In SlimDX they are set by default but in SharpDX you need to set them explicitly, this solves my issue. Thank you all for the help.